# Hg: Find out if a branch has been merged in to default?

Tags: merge, mercurial, branch

So I've got a long and detailed Mercurial Repository which has been worked on by several times over a long period of time with lots of branches, in that time no one knew that you can close a branch.

Recently I've closed nearly 1200 abandoned heads and it runs a lot better. However we have a number of branches which we want to preserve. Some I think may have already been merged back in to default but I'm not sure.

I can see if I run `hg branches` that they are marked as `(inactive)` meaning that it has been merged in to another branch but on checking its not merged directly back in to default. Is there a way I can check if somewhere these branches have been merged back in to default even if its via another branch ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish that with [revsets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets), in particular:

```
hg log -r "not ancestors(heads(default)) and head() and not closed()"
```

That should get you all heads of named branches that have not been closed and are not ancestors of (i.e. have not been merged into) the default branch.

Comment: Excellent that sorts out the next issue that had as well.